# How to install JRE in a way usable for dev?

Tags: install, java

I have Java 8 installed by an admin

- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`
- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin`

I needed to install java9, so I downloaded and installed the JDK to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

However, I got no `.../jre` folder!

When I tried to install the JRE as a standalone, the installation completed fine but there's nothing new under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` (or jdk-9.0.4.jdk)

I need to have the jre folder there or at least to know where it is so I can configure my way to it. 
How can this be achieved?

Comment: What path do you expect the jre folder to be? Doesn't running java from the bin directories you mention work?

Answer (score 1):

The Java 9 (and 10) JDK no longer includes a separate `jre` directory. Instead you just use the main JDK directory - the 'Contents/Home' directory.

The output of the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command will give you the directory to use.

Comment: That didn't work for eclipse. Luckily, /usr/bin did.